# `web3.py`: AttributeError: 'Contract' object has no attribute 'eventFilter'

Tags: events, web3.py

**Update:**

For `web3 v5.x.x`,

[Event Log Filters](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html?highlight=event#event-log-filters) is as follows:

> ```
> event_filter= myContract.events.<event_name>.createFilter(fromBlock="latest", argument_filters={'arg1':10}) 
> event_filter.get_new_entries()
> ```

---

***Goal:*** I want to print logs of the smart contract, like I do on `web3.js`, using `web3.py`.

On `web3.js` side, following code piece works:

```
var event = myContract.LogJob({}, {fromBlock:0, toBlock:'latest'});
event.watch(function(error, result) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

---

But on the web3.py side I was not able to make it work. :( I have followed following documentation.

```
event_filter = myContract.eventfilter('LogJob', {'filter': {'arg1':10}})
```

Error I am having:

```
AttributeError: 'Contract' object has no attribute 'eventFilter'
```

I have also tried following line of code, but it did not worked as well:

```
event = myContract.call().LogJob({}, {'fromBlock':100, 'toBlock':110});
```

**[Q]** Am I doing something wrong? How could I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use a v4 feature. Chances are good that you have v3 installed. To install the latest v4 version, use:

```
pip3 install --upgrade web3
```